# Solr schema: Is it safe to update schema type definitions when they are not used?

Tags: solr

When is it safe to update the Solr schema and keep the existing indexes?

I am upgrading Solr to version 7.2 now, and some type definitions in my old schema generate warnings in the log like:

```
Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.CurrencyField]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
```

Is it safe to update this type definition to the new `solr.CurrencyFieldType` and keep my existing indexes:

1. When the type **is not** used in the schema for document properties.
2. When the type **is** used in the schema for document properties.

Generally, what schema change will definitely require a total reindex of the documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the field isn't being used, you can do anything you like with it - the schema is Solr's way of enforcing validation and expose certain low level Lucene settings for field configuration. If you've never indexed any content using the field, then you can update the field definition (or maybe better, remove it if you're not using it) without reindexing.

However, if you change the definition of an existing field to a different type (for example, when the int type changed from being a TrieInt to a Point field), it's a general rule that you'll have to reindex to avoid getting random weird, untraceable issues.

For TextFields, if you're not changing the field type - i.e. the field is still of the same type, but you're changing the analysis or tokenization change for the field, you might not have to reindex. If the change is only to the query part of the analysis chain, no reindexing is needed - if the change is to the indexing part (or both), it depends on what the change is - the existing tokens stored in the index won't change, so if you have indexed content without lowercasing it, and then add for example a lowercase filter for querying, you won't get a match for any existing tokens that contain uppercase. In that case you'll have to reindex to make your collection work properly again.

Comment: Is it possible to redefine say a triedate field to a pointdate field and then reindex in place?

Comment: @MichaelConrad That depends on what you mean by "reindex in place"; Solr has no support for reindexing a core by itself; the content will have to be resubmitted. In that case you're going to be better off by creating a new collection or core, indexing into that and then swapping the cores or collections around afterwards (and if you're using collections in solrcloud, use a collection alias for querying so you can swap them around as necessary)